# Как разрешить пользователю ROLE_USER доступ к сервису SonataAdminBundle?

Tags: symfony2, symfony, sonata, fosuserbundle, role

Доброго времени суток!
Я действительно не могу найти ответ на мою проблему. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Итак. Имеется проект на Symfony 2.8. Есть модуль SonataAdminBundle + FOSUserBundle. Я создал несколько сервисов: User, Flat и Admin.
Вход в админку предоставляется при присутствии ROLE_USER и больше. При входе в админку с ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN все сервисы видны,а при входе с ROLE_USER не виден ни один сервис. Различные манипуляции с кодом не дали никаких результатов, может быть кто знает как правильно Предоставить пользователю с ROLE_USER доступ к сервису Admin???

**security.yml**

```
security:
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
admin.admin:
    class: Flatbel\FlatBundle\Admin\AdminAdmin
    arguments: [~, Flatbel\FlatBundle\Entity\Flat,~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Admin}
```

**AdminAdmin.php**

```
class AdminAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
```

{

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('userid')
    ;
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')
        ->addIdentifier('userid')
       ;
}

public function toString($object)
{
    return $object instanceof User
        ? $object->getUsername()
        : 'Flat'; // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('userid')
    ;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Необходимость дать доступ пользователю в административный раздел с теми же сервисами звучит, как позволить быть пользователю супер админом. Назначьте роль по умолчанию ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN для всех пользователей.

Это решение звучит очень странно, но это то, что позволит решить вашу проблему, и оно полностью отвечает на ваш вопрос.

Если вы все же не хотите делать всех пользователей администраторами, то вам лучше посмотреть в сторону отдельного пространства для них (Profile). [Sonata Demo](http://demo.sonata-project.org/). Попробуйте зайти в административный раздел за обычного пользователя и за администратора, разницу вы сразу поймете суть реализации.

Или вы можете обратиться к ролевому разделению админов с помощью голосующих (Voters), если, опять же, вы не хотите, чтобы все сервисы были доступны всем. Тогда для всех пользователей по умолчанию вы ставите `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, а для крутого админа `ROLE_CHUCK_NORRIS` (но лучше `ROLE_SITE_OWNER`), которому вы с помощью Voters дадите доступ к закрытым сервисам.

Эта роль обязательно должна быть отнаследована от `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, так как все внутренности (дефолтные конфиги) сонаты заточены под неё.